# Android onItemClickListener does not work (No focusables in code)

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener

This has been driving me crazy over the past several hours... and I feel like it's something obvious...

I've gotten my code down to a simple ListView with a single TextView in it, but still can't seem to make it work (I don't see the toast or log message in the console).

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SparseArray<Data> data = createData();
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        final CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, data);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.v("onItemClick", "Clicked");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**CustomListAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final SparseArray<Data> data;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final Activity activity;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, SparseArray<Data> data) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.data = data;
        this.inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        Log.v("getItem", "" + position);
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        //TODO: Implement Image vs no image views
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parentView) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.data, null);
        }

        Data data = (Data) getItem(position);

        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dataTitle)).setText(data.getTitle());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:background="@color/background" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/background" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**data.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/dataTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:textColor="@color/dataTitle" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**NOTE:** I do see that the touch even is at least being registered by the device:

```
07-15 22:00:50.734: I/InputReader(804): Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.23535 ] when=378716384422000
07-15 22:00:50.734: I/InputDispatcher(804): Delivering touch to: action: 0x4
07-15 22:00:50.734: I/InputDispatcher(804): Delivering touch to: action: 0x0
```

Comment: For the lazy and uninitiated like me - SSCCE -  Short, Self Contained, Correct Example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Remove `android:clickable="false"` from the TextView.
2. Also, remove `android:focusable="false"`.

You can't catch clicks if you have these set as false.

Secondly,

```
@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

Return `true` in these methods. You won't be able to catch clicks if these return `false` for every item.

IMO it's not a good idea to override methods that you do not necessarily have to or are unsure as to what the method should return.

Comment: Those where added out of desperation... It still doesn't work without those attributes :(

Comment: You are a life saver... seriously!  A single line change over hours of head bashing!  Thank you so much!